# Box plot (ggplot2) with custom groupings

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in the following form:

```
sample <- data.frame(
  id = c(seq(1,9,1)),
  drives = sample(0:1, 9, replace = T),
  bikes = sample(0:1, 9, replace = T),
  outcomes = sample(1000:3000, 9, replace = F))
)
```

I would like to create a boxplot using ggplot2 with outcomes on the y-axis and the following groups on the x-axis: (1) people who drive (regardless of whether they bike), (2) people who bike (regardless of whether they drive), (2) people who neither drive nor bike. However, I'm having trouble, since I'm unclear how to assign a single ID (i.e. observation) to multiple groups. I just know how to assign groups based on a single variable:

```
p <- ggplot(sample, aes(x=as.factor(drives), y=outcomes)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
p
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new data frame with these logical tests encoded as a factor:

```r
df <- rbind(cbind(sample[sample$drives == 1,], group = "drives"), 
            cbind(sample[sample$bikes == 1,], group = "bikes"), 
            cbind(sample[sample$drives == 0 & sample$bikes == 0,], group = "neither"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=group, y=outcomes)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]